# MySQL output most visited locations

Tags: mysql, sql, database, location, coordinates

I've got a table in a MySQL-database with thousands of checkins from my phone. Every x seconds, a new location is inserted.

This is how the table looks like:

```html
+----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
| id | lat       | lon      | date       | timestamp  |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
| 1  | 51.650586 | 5.622935 | 14-08-2018 | 1534233062 |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
| 2  | 51.65181  | 5.622228 | 14-08-2018 | 1534230962 |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
| 3  | 51.653715 | 5.6194   | 14-08-2018 | 1534230121 |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
```

Besides the GPS coordinates, date and timestamp I'm saving address data from the Google Maps Geocode API too, but street names aren't always right so it's not useful to use for data grouping.

I'm currently displaying the last inserted location on a Google Map using JavaScript, just as a single pointer. I'm looking for a MySQL-query that outputs a list of the 5 most visited locations for a defined date. There are a few hundred location check-ins a day.

It would be great if they could be grouped together, with a distance set of 500 meters. So for example, the 3 locations from above will be grouped together as the distance between them is less than 500 meters.

Could somebody help me writing a query for this? All help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What if every point is within 500m of another point?

Comment: PostgreSQL has built-in geographic column types. Maybe could be a better fit.

Comment: I'd recommend using MongoDB for this. It has built-in geocoding features, and should be a better solution for your task.

Comment: MySQL supports openGIS (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html) if you want to incorporate spatial elements into your queries.